# product of list using continuation

Tags: ocaml, multiplication, continuations, continuation-passing

my goal is to write a times function of type `int list -> int` that that takes a list of `int`s and, **using continuations**, returns an `int` such that that `int` = multiplication of all the `int`s in the `int list`. 
for instance `times [2;2;3]` returns `12`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
let times l = 
 let rec times' l c = match l with
 | [] -> c []
 | h::h2::t -> times' (h*h2::t) (fun r -> c ( r))
 | h :: [] -> times' [] (fun r -> c (h::[]))
 in
  times' l (fun r -> r) ;;
```

Problems with my code

1. it returns an int list with one element which is the result (multiplication of all `int`s in the inputed `int list`)
2. I feel like this is not really using continuations, this seems to be a normal tail recursive function but I am not sure since I am still not very familiar with this programming style.

Comment: I can't see how you'd be able to implement CPS with a function of that type at all. I would think it should instead be `int list -> (int -> unit) -> unit`.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought any function that could be written in a tail_recursive manner can be re-written using CPS :o is this not true then ?

Comment: CPS is passing the "return" value via the continuation, which means the function _doesn't_ return, at least within the context of CPS. To get the external function to return a value normally you'd have to return that value through the entire "CPS" call chain, which means it's not CPS, just tail recursion.

Comment: It should be true that you can rewrite any tail recursive function as CPS, but not without changing the type signature.

Comment: In continuation passing style, functions do not "return" as we do in the default style.

Comment: You can rewrite any program in continuation passing style, not only tail recursive functions, a nice property is that when you do so all the calls become tail calls.

Answer (score 1):

You did computation in arguments in manner of recursive calls, but you should do it in continuation. For CPS, what you should do is to "grow" a given continuation.

```
let times l =
  let rec aux l c =
    match l with
    | [] -> c 1  (* I assume that (times []) is one, and pass it to the next computation c. *)
    | n::ns -> aux ns (fun x -> c (n * x))  (* In a new continuation: For a given value x, multiply by n, and pass it to the next computation c. *)
  in aux l (fun r -> r)
```

Also, examples which explain differences between CPS and direct style, written in ["Continuation-passing style"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) in Wikipedia may help.